# Wordpress trigger 404

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

How can I trigger a 404 template to show up ? I have done the following ...

```
$_escaped_fragment_ = $_REQUEST['_escaped_fragment_'];
$post = ( get_page_by_path($_escaped_fragment_,'','brands' ) );
if(!empty($post) ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    the_title();
    get_template_part('loop');
    wp_reset_postdata();
}else{
    get_404_template();//not working
    include( get_query_template( '404' ) );//not working...
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you do var_dump($post)?

Answer (score 7):

How about this? this should work.

```
status_header(404);
include( get_404_template() );
exit;
```

instead of this

```
get_404_template();//not working
include( get_query_template( '404' ) );//not working...
```

Comment: Thanks much for this, exactly what I was looking for. Wish I could mark it as the correct answer :)